# How to project after lookup without the 'as' field mongoose

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following code:

```
     const products: ReadonlyArray<Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'gender' | 'category' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>> = await UserDB.aggregate<
        Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'gender' | 'category' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>>([
          {
            $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId) },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'products',
              localField: 'inBagProducts',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'product',
            },
          },
          {
            $unwind: '$product',
          },
          {
            $project: { 
              product: {
                'product.category': 1,
                'product.gender': 1,
                'product.title': 1,
                'product.description': 1,
                'product.price': 1,
                'product.imageFileName': 1,
              }
            },
          },
        ]);
```

This code gives this as a result:

```
    {
        _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
        product: {
          category: 1,
          gender: 2,
          title: 'jdwoeid',
          description: 'jfwoeifjweoi',
          price: 23902,
          imageFileName: '1628808613195-7886.png'
        }
      },
      {
        _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
        product: {
          category: 5,
          gender: 1,
          title: 'sivdosi',
          description: 'oisbdvoi',
          price: 2394,
          imageFileName: 'http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png'
        }
      }
```

Expected result is this:

```
      {
        _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
          category: 1,
          gender: 2,
          title: 'jdwoeid',
          description: 'jfwoeifjweoi',
          price: 23902,
          imageFileName: '1628808613195-7886.png'
      },
      {
        _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
          category: 5,
          gender: 1,
          title: 'sivdosi',
          description: 'oisbdvoi',
          price: 2394,
          imageFileName: 'http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png'
      }
```

How can I have the result without the `product: {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$addFields` pipeline to add `_id` to the `product` property, and then you can use `$replaceRoot` pipeline. You can add these aggregation stages to your code:

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "product._id": "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$product"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VVxXgDYFANI